# how to send a struct larger than 32byte over nrf24l01

Tags: nodemcu, arduino-esp8266

i have three nodemcu and I want to send a struct over nRF24l01+ , but my struct size is 52 byte and the nRf24l01+ module is just sending 32 byte !
how should I send my struct ?

my struct :

```
struct fullData{
  unsigned long ttime;
  String data1;
  String data2;
  String data3;
  String data4;
  }sndData,recData;
```

I tried this way but it dosen't work :

transmitter code:

```
void sendOverRadio(){
  char data[sizeof(sndData)];
  memcpy(data, &sndData, sizeof(sndData));
  radio.stopListening();
  int z = 0;
  for(int i= 0 ; i<2 ; i++){
    char dt[32];
    dt[0] = i;
    for(int j =1 ; j<32;j++){
      dt[j]=data[z];
      z +=1;
    }
    radio.write(&dt , sizeof(dt));
  }
  radio.startListening();
}
```

receiver code :

```
char data[sizeof(recData)];
void loop(){
  if(radio.available()){
    Serial.println("Radio Available...");
    char dt[32];

    while (radio.available()){
      radio.read(&dt, sizeof(dt));
    }
    if(dt[0]==0){
         memset(data, 0, sizeof(data));
         memcpy(data, &dt[1], 32);
      }else if(dt[0]==1){
        memcpy(&data[32], &dt[1], 32);
        memcpy(&recData, data, sizeof(recData));
      }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[RF24Network](https://github.com/nRF24/RF24Network) library handles payload splitting. Send your struct like this:

```
  RF24NetworkHeader header(0, 'D');
  if (!NETWORK.write(header, &sndData, sizeof(sndData))) {
    Serial.println(F("Error."));
  } else {
    Serial.println(F("Success."));
  }
```